# How to search and find multiple field values... using MongoDB and I tried with regex

Tags: regex, mongodb, model

I am trying to find 3 different field values while searching with .find() method and it gives either complete data or only one.

This is the code I have given:

```
const search = req.query.search || "";

const Rest = await Restaurant.find(
                                   {name:{$regex:search,$options:"i"}},
                                   {locality:{$regex:search,$options:'i'}},
                                   {"cuisine.name":{$regex:search,$options:'i'})
```

I am getting an empty array as output, as I mentioned multiple fields together in .find()..

I am getting output if I use the below code(i.e) find only one field..

```
const Rest = await Restaurant.find({name:{$regex:search,$options:"i"}})
```

If I search for any of the 3 fields name/locality/cuisine.name I should get appropriate output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original query was incorrect. Those conditions should be *grouped* into one parameter. It should be as below:

```
const Rest = await Restaurant.find({
  name: {
    $regex: search,
    $options: "i"
  },
  locality: {
    $regex: search,
    $options: "i"
  },
  "cuisine.name": {
    $regex: search,
    $options: "i"
  }
})
```

The above query will work the matching in **AND** conditions (all filter criteria must be fulfilled).

Instead, you need to work the query in **OR** conditions with the `$or` operator (either one of the filter criteria needed to be fulfilled).

**Solution**

```
const Rest = await Restaurant.find({
  $or: [
    {
      name: {
        $regex: search,
        $options: "i"
      }
    },
    {
      locality: {
        $regex: search,
        $options: "i"
      }
    },
    {
      "cuisine.name": {
        $regex: search,
        $options: "i"
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vn_6lBk35W0)

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked...even I tried with $or but used {} instead of [] and received an error....

Answer (score 0):

You can look at $and operator and $or operator in Mongodb, You can use $and operator if you want to match all of the given parameters or $or operator if one must match. Like this:

```
const Rest = await Restaurant.find({
  $and: [
    { name: { $regex: search, $options: "i" } },
    { locality: { $regex: search, $options: "i" } },
    { "cuisine.name": { $regex: search, $options: "i" } },
  ],
});
```

See the documentation:

[$and operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)

[$or operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)